# Why can I sometimes click on the edges of a maximized window?

Tags: xfce, xubuntu

I apologize if this question is vague. I've seen this oddity happen differently not just between programs, but between Firefox profiles, so I'm understandably quite confused. And have no idea how to give replication steps.

My issue is that that some of my maximized windows are behaving differently from others. In some, they work just how I'd expect and their content takes up all of my screen except for the panel, meaning that they have no "edge" from which I could resize them without unmaximizing. In other maximized windows, I can move my cursor to any of their edges, and I will discover that my cursor is truly on an edge and therefore I'm capable of resizing a window that claims to be maximized. Stranger still, I've discovered that RStudio has this issue on all of its edges except for its right one.

**Why does this inconsistency exist?** It's causing some very annoying behaviour. For example, if my cursor is in the wrong place while I'm trying to use it to scroll up my maximized text editor of choice (Geany), I sometimes end up resizing the window and ending up in a completely unintended place.

I am currently running Xubuntu 20.20, which I believe puts me on version 4.14 of Xfce.

Comment: A way of reliable reproducing it would help a lot.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Are you implying that this isn't normal Xfce behavior? That's a good sign, As for reproduction, it's simply a matter of opening a program and maximizing it. For example, I get this issue in Thunar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, Xfce renders applications designed for Gnome 3 with no sizing frame, preventing resize when maximized, and other applications with a frame. Some applications have options that effect the window frame, so the user can set it to their preference. In Firefox, the `Title Bar checkbox` at the lower left of the `Toolbars > Customize...` page controls whether or not a frame is provided; this may be able to be set on a per-profile basis (haven't tested to find out).

This doesn't explain all of your issue, such as the odd behavior of RStudio (which I also haven't tested), but hopefully it can help someone to provide a complete answer... and nab the 50 points! :^)

*Update...*

As discovered by @J.Mini following my answer, the whole problem can be resolved with a couple of mouse clicks. Go to `Settings -> Window Manager Tweaks -> Accessibility`, enable the options `Hide frame of window when maximized` and `Hide title of window when maximized`, and then everything is fixed.

Comment: Your Firefox example is completely correct. The setting that you've mentioned appears to have complete control over whether or not I experience my issue.

Comment: You've got it! Go to Settings -> Window Manager Tweaks -> Accessibility. and enable the options 'Hide frame of window when maximized' and 'Hide title of window when maximized' and then everything is fixed.

Comment: Wow! I don't think I ever noticed that Tweaks setting!

Comment: It's in a stupid place. Why Accessibility? Anyway, make an edit and the bounty's yours.